# How to a clickable url / email / phone number on UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I am receiving a server response as a sting that can contain some url or email address or phone number ie same string can have all three of them or one number and couple of url. Nothing is fixed.

I am using UITextView to show this sting on device. Now what I want is these url/email/phone number show up as hyperlink and on clicking these hyperlink user should be able to see a webpage if its a url, draft and send an email if its email address or call the number when clicked on number hyper link

Can anyone suggest me a way to do this. Or suggest any other data view to be used which can make things easy

Comment: You might want to make sure you go through and accept answers that help you.

Comment: Retagged from UITableView to UITextView. The question does not mention UITableView.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Set the data detector types of your `UITextView`. There are a number of options:

> UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber
>
> UIDataDetectorTypeLink
>
> UIDataDetectorTypeAddress
>
> UIDataDetectorTypeCalendarEvent
>
> UIDataDetectorTypeNone
>
> UIDataDetectorTypeAll

So, in your case, you'd probably like to do:

```
self.myTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

Comment: You know how Can I make the link underlined?

Comment: You can set the style of links in `UITextView` by setting the `UITextView.linkTextAttributes` property (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618632-linktextattributes)

Answer (score 6):

Also note that the textview should not be editable when you use `NSDataDetectorTypes`.

Let textView be an object for `UITextView`, then set:

```
textView.editable = NO;
```

then only it can detect the links, phone numbers, address etc.

Answer (score 3):

Add a UITextView in Interface Builder. No code needed. In Attributes Inspector, uncheck "Editable" and do check "Selectable". Do check "Phone Number" beside Data Detectors. Should work for other data types. DO be sure to edit the "Hint color" or else it may appear as no label is there (but you can still touch to launch). (Its a beautiful world, if you look at it the right way!)

Comment: "Tint" color! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an UIButton, and change the title into the URL, email or phone number.

Create a custom UIButton with the corresponding format to make it look like a normal sentence (the edges and background of the button have the same color as the background of the view).

Format the text to make it look blue (and optionally underlined) like [this](http://example) so people know it's a hyperlink.

Comment: How Can I make the recognized link to be underlined? Links doest work.